# Accessing bitcoind from python module hits error

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, op-return

I am experimenting with the blockchain a bit, specifically trying to use the [python-OP_RETURN module](https://github.com/coinspark/python-OP_RETURN/issues) to put a few bytes into the blockchain op_return field.  To use this module I blv I need a running bitcoin core instance so I installed bitcoind using a downloaded .tar.gz (and not thru the ppa which raised some system issues iirc). Anyway, I have the bitcoind daemon running and by writing a bitcoin.conf file it seems I can avoid devoting 200+GB to this by using the prune paramter. I also set the following in bitcoin.conf:

```
rpcuser=myuser
rpcpassword=mypassword
testnet=0
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=1.2.3.4
server=1
```

and now wanted to try putting some bytes into the blockchain :

```
jeremy@instance-1:~$ python3 python-OP_RETURN/store-OP_RETURN.py 'This example stores 47 bytes in the blockchain.'
testnet False  [**this is debug info I printed]
url http://127.0.0.1:8332/ req {'id': '1620597001.3218298-441058', 'method': 'getinfo', 'params': ()}  [**this is also debug info I printed]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python-OP_RETURN/store-OP_RETURN.py", line 47, in <module>
    result=OP_RETURN_store(data, testnet)
  File "/home/jeremy/python-OP_RETURN/OP_RETURN.py", line 116, in OP_RETURN_store
    if not OP_RETURN_bitcoin_check(testnet):
  File "/home/jeremy/python-OP_RETURN/OP_RETURN.py", line 410, in OP_RETURN_bitcoin_check
    info=OP_RETURN_bitcoin_cmd('getinfo', testnet)
  File "/home/jeremy/python-OP_RETURN/OP_RETURN.py", line 477, in OP_RETURN_bitcoin_cmd
    raw_result=urlopen(url, json.dumps(request).encode('utf-8'), OP_RETURN_NET_TIMEOUT).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1034, in http_error_401
    url, req, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 987, in http_error_auth_reqed
    return self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 997, in retry_http_basic_auth
    return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

So my question is how I would avoid the 404 , and/or why its happening.
The url and request from line 477 are

http://127.0.0.1:8332/
and
{'id': '1620597001.3218298-441058', 'method': 'getinfo', 'params': ()} respectively. Should I use telnet maybe to check if the host:port is responding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I am getting weird errors using [python-OP_RETURN](https://github.com/coinspark/python-OP_RETURN/), last commit in this repository was in 2017 so maybe we need to make few changes in the code.

If you want to experiment with OP_RETURN, it can be done using Bitcoin Core. Example:

Convert string to hex: https://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter

```
createrawtransaction '[]' '{"data":"616c69616268617474"}'
```

```
fundrawtransaction 02000000000100000000000000000b6a09616c6961626861747400000000
```

```
signrawtransactionwithwallet 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
```

```
sendrawtransaction 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
```

[image: op-return-example-tx]

[image: op-return-details]

Tx: [`d3ba03164365d8a644dfc0fa221d367ff083463d67bfc5fcbbdc2643c3623bc5`](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/d3ba03164365d8a644dfc0fa221d367ff083463d67bfc5fcbbdc2643c3623bc5)

**Python code to achieve the same thing using [AuthServiceProxy](https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc) Python JSON-RPC interface:**

```
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy

rpc_port = 18444
rpc_user = 'user3'
rpc_password = 'password3'

rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:%s"%(rpc_user,rpc_password,rpc_port))

OP_RETURN_HEX = "aliabhatt".encode("utf-8").hex()
print(OP_RETURN_HEX)

create_tx = rpc_connection.createrawtransaction([],{"data":OP_RETURN_HEX})
print(create_tx)

fund_tx = rpc_connection.fundrawtransaction(create_tx)
print(fund_tx)

sign_tx = rpc_connection.fundrawtransaction(fund_tx['hex'])
print(sign_tx)

send_tx = rpc_connection.fundrawtransaction(sign_tx['hex'])
print(send_tx)
```

Comment: ok thanks - it does seem to be old sw no longer in sync with bitcoin core, i'll see if i can patch it up

Comment: If you want to use python for creating OP_RETURN transaction, I can update the answer with a different approach.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm after.

Comment: @jeremy_rutman I have added python code in the answer

Comment: I did `pip install bitcoinrpc` and wind up with a module version 0.4.0  that doesnt seem to have an `authproxy` method like you use. My bitconrpc has bitcoin_rpc and BitcoinRPC objects, the first of which has methods like BestBlockHash and the latter of which has methods like getblock

Comment: Ok it seems https://pypi.org/project/python-requests-bitcoinrpc/  is using the same name for their python module?  In any case when I install that, I get your mthods

Comment: The rpc_connection seems to get made but the first createrawtransaction hits a 500 error, do you have any advice?

Comment: Let's discuss in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8089/mempool