# What tools can I use to create and replace RBF transactions?

Tags: python, replace-by-fee, sequence

I'd like to create transactions within my python application, that support replace-by-fee RBF (BIP125).

Apparently, if I want to be able to replace my transaction later on, I need to signal that already in the first transaction. I saw that I'd have to do something with the sequence field for that, but I didn't quite understand it.

Is there any library that would help me with that, or do I need to craft this transaction manually, and if yes, how?

Sorry for being so vague, but this RBF-stuff is giving me a hard time.

Reading the answer to the question [What restrictions are there to the application of opt-in RBF?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49517/what-restrictions-are-there-to-the-application-of-opt-in-rbf), is only confusing me more.
Why would setting the sequence number to `MAX-1` mean 2 things at the same time (`transaction uses locktime` and `transaction is replaceable`)?
What if I don't want to use locktime but only make my transaction replaceable?

Comment: You can use AuthServiceProxy Python JSON-RPC interface. Example: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/106192/ To create a transaction which has RBF enabled you need to set `replaceable` as `true` in [createrawtransaction](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/rawtransactions/createrawtransaction/) or [fundrawtransaction](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/rawtransactions/fundrawtransaction/) and [bumpfee](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/bumpfee/) to replace transaction with a higher fee