# Creating an OP_Return TX with Python bitcoinlib

Tags: python, op-return, python-bitcoinlib

How can I create an op_return TX with python bitcoinlib?

The transaction should include the OP_RETURN HEX-Data and an address where I send my change money

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing bitcoind from python module hits error](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/106187/accessing-bitcoind-from-python-module-hits-error)

Comment: @Prayank Python-bitcoinlib is a library that natively implements the Bitcoin protocol; it is not an RPC library for communicating with Bitcoin Core.

Comment: Okay. Retracted duplicate close vote.

Comment: Have you tried working with the examples from the github documentation? https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/0ea83c4fd499c63823754627c69ebdd79dc0d62c/examples/timestamp-op-ret.py#L59

Comment: Any update about some new code for this? Above link is from 2015